# Using Arduino Serial to turn on LED. What is my error?

Tags: arduino, led

```
void setup(){
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
    if (Serial.available() > 0){
       int inChar = Serial.read();
       if (inChar == 'H'){
           digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
       }
       if (inChar == 'L'){
        digitalWrite(13, LOW); 
       }
    }
}
```

I have seen very similar programs. I don't get any compile errors, but the led light won't turn on. Is there an error in my code? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a hardware issue. Double check that first.

Comment: I can get other simple programs to run (like a blink program).I added     Serial.println(inChar); When I type in the serial monitor I expected to see it printed out, but I see nothing. So maybe there is a problem with how the serial monitor is set up.

Comment: Solved. I didn't realize that I had to press the "send" button on the serial monitor. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

Use a digital multimeter (DMM) to read the voltage between pin 13 and Arduino ground.  It should output 5V when you send the 'H'.  If it does, then your problem is the LED.  If it does not output 5V when you send the 'H' then you have a software or serial communication issue.

Double check that you have the correct BAUD rate and COM port settings in whatever program is talking to the Arduino.

Comment: If I click on tools it shows COM3 which is what also shows on the serial monitor. How could I check if 9600 isn't the correct baud rate? The serial monitor shows 9600 baud.

Comment: So long as COM3 is the only option in the Tools->Serial Port menu list, then it sounds like you have your serial montior set up correctly.  Are you sending a capital 'H' (not lower case)?

Comment: I just tried this exact code on my Arduino Mega, it works just fine.

Comment: Solved. I didn't realize that I had to press the "send" button on the serial monitor. Thanks for the input.